# How to solve Installation is incomplete error in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

I have got below error while install Magento 2.3. I am not a programmer, I'm just newbie and try to learn.

```
    [ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in /home/jm4viwna9q3f/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
    Stack trace:

#0 /home/jm4viwna9q3f/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/jm4viwna9q3f/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/jm4viwna9q3f/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 ,
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it default magento? or you have some data?

Comment: i have some data, i import i file on my database. its a magento theme

Comment: you have to install magento first, then install all other themes and extensions.

Comment: i did install magento first, i only import those files in database,i will try again. thank you